# How to make CollectionView cell height depend on total of all element height in the cell?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, swift4

I know this question may asked so many time,but I still cant be understand on this.I very new in iOS developement,I come from Android.

I have a `CollectionViewCell` look something like this:

[image]

I set all the autoLayout for each element in StoryBoard. But the problem is the height of each element in each cell may be different in runtime.

Example the height of `Image` in photo above will be taller or shorter,sometimes the `Text 1` and `Image` will `GONE`(I set it programmatically), because of all this different scenario,the height of each cell will be different.

In Android,I just set the cell height to `wrap_content`,but I really dont know how to do it in iOS.

So my question is,how to make the cell height change to fit the total height of all element inside the cell?

Comment: You can use `estimatedItemSize`. This may help: https://engineering.shopspring.com/dynamic-cell-sizing-in-uicollectionview-fd95f614ef80

Comment: @MikeTaverne hey bro,my `collectionview` is created in storyboard itself,but not in a `nib`,so how can I set the `estimatedItemSize` in my `ViewController`?Can u elaborate more??

Comment: @ken : Is the height of the imageView fixed or its varying as well ??

Comment: imageView is varying as well..sorry for late of reply